# Total number of 6502s or 8051s ever manufactured or sold?

Tags: microprocessor

What's a good way to estimate the total number of 6502 or 8051 chips (or workalikes, pin-compatible or not, but not including software or FPGA emulators) ever manufactured or sold?

Added:

(To clarify, for the 8051, I'm asking about a estimate regarding the number integrated circuit devices that execute the original basic 8051 ISA directly using hardwired transistors dedicated at fabrication time for executing the 8051 ISA, or an inclusive proper superset.  Similar question for the 6502 ISA. Disregard differences in the originally documented as unimplemented instruction space.)

Comment: Note that the 8051 is still in production: ATMEL sells pin-compatible variants as well as non-pin-compatible variants that have USB and other "new" features. All using Flash ROM instead of EPROM.

Comment: A search for "8051" on DigiKey just turned up 3609 results in the Microcontrollers category, across 13 manufacturers. Filtering out the ARM and similar chaff  brings the result down just a bit, to 3588 products. A lot of that is going to be alternate packaging options for the same basic processor, but the point is, 8051 is still a going thing.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if a 6502 variant was also still in production embedded somewhere.

Comment: @Wilson Indeed WDC still manufactures the improved variant of the 6502. However I doubt that it is sold in larger amounts. Note that unlike the 8051 the 6502 is a microprocessor requiring external memory and other components. If 65816-based microcontrollers also count as 6502, I can imagine that these chips still are sold in larger amounts.

Comment: @MartinRosenau The missing point here is that 'the 8051' and 'the 6502' arn't the used by themelf much (and haven't been over the last 30 years). The are CPU cores implemented in microconrtrolers with many peripherals. Like the Siemens 80515 (8051) or RENESAS 740 (6502) family. There where many 6502 cored microcontrollers with no need for external components. Already in the 80's these versions have outnumbered the base models by far. For the 6502 think Rockwell modem chipsets, Nintendo games ... or, o horror: Furbys!

Comment: I'm wondering what is 'software' or 'FPGA' emulators for you? Do you consider netlist-level simulator of 6502 at visual6502.org as 'software emulator' as well, and if yes, why? Do you consider gate-level design of 6502, translated into HDL and then compiled to work inside an FPGA, as 'fpga emulator' as well?

Comment: And just to continue, WDC (Western design center) offers both hard and soft macros of 6502. Will you consider products containing those IP cores as 'emulators' or should they count as well?

Comment: @Raffzahn My point is: Today there are still 100% pin-compatible variants of the 8051. And even the other 8051-compatible chips do the same an original 8051 did: They work as microntroller (with on-chip GPIO, UARTs, timers, memory ...). The original 6502 was a pure CPU without any on-chip peripherals or memory. Now the question is: Does a 6502-based microcontroller (with on-chip peripherals and memory) count as "6502" or not? This question has to be answered before the original question can be answered.

Comment: @MartinRosenau The question is including all such variations ("or workalikes, pin-compatible or not"). Also is the 6502 not onl still in production (WDC65C02) but has been available in versions incuding various perhipherals (including dual CPU core variants) from the early deays on. So, again, what's your point?

Comment: @Raffzahn I already wrote that the 65C02 is still produced, but I doubt that a large number is sold. My point is: Because the 6502 has no GPIO pins (unlike the 6510), the **only** function an original 6502 is to exchange data using an external data bus. A Renesas 380L seems to be a 6502-based microcontroller **without** external data bus. This means that the **only** function of a 6502 (exchanging data with an external data bus) is not supported by the 380L. Is the 380L a "work-alike" device? On the other hand you could argue that the 380L **contains** a 6502 internally...

Comment: Just wave your arms and say "A lot. A whole lot."

Comment: @Raffzahn You still don't get my point: You write: "*he explicit asks to include variations*". He has to be more precise to get an answer here. To understand me, you have to know that Acorn claimed that the ARM CPU was designed to be as close to the 6502 as possible to make it easier for BBC users to use the Archimedes. This however would mean that ARM7TDMI could be seen as "variation" of the 6502. If you do so, the 6502 was sold more often than all x86-compatibles together! All I want to say: You have to define more precisely what "work-alike" means.

Comment: @MartinRosenau Come on, ARM is in no way a work alike. Just try a simple step with me: I think it's easy for most to agree that a 6800 is not a 6500 alike.  Can you? If so, then we already have a great concept eliminating anything ARM - even remote. Instead of pulling far fetched examples to dis some question I prefer to use common sense. And sta positive. In this case for example assume that variation means keeping the basic programming model. Doesn't that sound like a reasonable assumption to you? (In addition, if you think it's to broad, vote for it to be closed.)

Comment: @Raffzahn But this exactly is the question: What does "work-alike" mean? Binary compatible instruction set? Source compatible instruction set? And what does "6502 chip" (explicitly mentioned in the question) mean? Do the major 6502 lines have to be available at the pins of the chip to be a "6502 chip" or is it sufficient that a 6502 is part of the chip (but the 6502 is only connected to internal circuits)? Is a 8051 with "modern" functions (such as USB OTG) still a "8051 chip"? I think depending on the answers to these questions the number of 8051/6502 chips sold varies massively!

Comment: Does 8051 include the 8051 family like 8052, 8751, 8752, 8031, 8032?

Comment: Are they ISA compatible?

Comment: 8051s are likely to be uncountable. There are super-cheap versions like the [STC15L104E](http://41j.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/stc15f104.jpg) and many more still being produced (see: [Battle of the 8051s](https://jaycarlson.net/microcontrollers/#battle-of-the-8051s)).

Answer (score 11):

Almost impossible to tell. Both CPUs have been sold by quite a lot of manufacturers in many variations - including knockoffs modified in some way to avoid royalties.

One hint might be the claim of 5 to 10 billion (*1) on the [WDC site](http://www.westerndesigncenter.com/wdc/):

[image: The legendary 65xx brand microprocessors with both 8-bit and 8/16-bit ISA’s keep cranking out the unit volumes in ASIC and standard microcontroller forms supplied by WDC and WDC’s licensees. Annual volumes in the hundreds (100’s) of millions of units keep adding in a significant way to the estimated shipped volumes of five (5) to ten (10) billion units. With 200MHz+ 8-bit W65C02S and 100MHz+ 8/16-bit W65C816S processors coming on line in ASIC and FPGA forms, we see these annual volumes continuing for a long, long time.]

Since WDC is nowadays the major licensor (*2) and still can only give it with such a huge uncertainty, I doubt anyone will be able to give a better one.

I think it's safe to assume this as well for Intel ... except, here the numbers may be way higher. 8051 (and derivatives) have been in heavy use all around the world by major suppliers.

---

*1 - US Billion, Milliards to others, 10^9 for serious minded.

*2 - MOS/Commodore gone for good, most others as well, there is still RENESAS and Rockwell, except I'm not sure if they license the core at all.

Comment: There are now several 8051 cores: basic cores with 12 clocks per cycle, derivatives with 6 clocks per instruction and 2 clocks (all those are much alike since they keep count of cycles per every instruction), and as well, cores with 4 clocks per cycle and 1 clock per cycle, where cycle counts are broken. Then again, while still being compatible on ISA level, they all have completely different designs, made presumably from scratch every time. Shouldn't they again count as 'FPGA/HDL/silicon emulators'? :)

Comment: And just to make my point clear: if one reverse-engineers some retro CPU core down to transistor level, recreates gates and generates HDL that behaves exactly the same (with the possible exception of too-much-analog things like unstable undocumented instructions in 6502), this is what I wouldn't count as an emulator, be is new silicon, FPGA firmware or netlist simulator running on PC. Everything else is more or less an "emulator", including compatible cores made from scratch.

Comment: Why did you roll back the edit? Do you have any specific reason to have a screenshot instead of textual citate?

Comment: Yes, it's to document what (and how) has been shown the web site. The picture is explicit meant to do so. The claim itself is well stated in the text part. Citing the website in text doesn't add anything, but removes the 'proof'

Comment: Don't forget that using text, rather than screenshots, is preferable as it assists web browsers for the blind. - https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/165/276

Comment: @Chenmunka Sure, but for one the text is included in the description, thus readers for the blind will provide them, but more important, it is **not** about the text, as this is an advertisement, and as such not content of the answer - only a reference of how it was shown. The relevant claim is mentioned in the main text. Think of it like pictures in other answers as well ... Thinking of it, how many do use the alternate text at all?

Comment: @Raffzahn:  I don't disagree with you.  Just trying to remind people.  In practice roughly half of images posted get alt text.  I do add text to images when I notice that it is missing but nobody can catch them all.

Comment: @Chenmunka Cool with me. I usually try to do it, but then again, it is easy overlooked (and I'm not doing many pics anyway).

Comment: Note, I think the proof-value of a screenshot nears zero. If you want proof-level reference, I would suggest to put an archive.org link (which is the custom also in the case of dead links). If the page wouldn't be archived by archive.org yet, you can also create an archive snapshot. Having archive.org link is proof-level - anybody can create screenshots, but only very few can do anything with archive.org snapshots.

Comment: @peterh An embedded snapshoot is for sure more reliable than another external link - but I guess everyone is entitled to a different opinion. In any case, there is no need to verbatim copy advertisements and promote them, or should we?

Comment: For having seen the source code of Rockwell based modem chipset (remember the Hayes POTS modems?). They all used a 6502 based microcontrollers. They were also running at insane frequencies. The model we had signed the NDA for (was in the 33600 bps generation of modems) ran at 70Mhz if I remember correctly. They were coupled with a DSP to decode the line signal. The µC handled the protocol (HDLC synchronous) and the interpreter (the famous AT+ commands).

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the 8051:

- One in most OSD-capable CRT monitors or television sets ever sold.
- One in most pre-DVD CDROM drives ever sold.
- One in most pre-2000s hard drives.
- A predecessor of the 8051 (the 8042. An 8048 derivative. The 8048 is NOT an 8051 per se, the 8051 was developed as a solution to do what the 8048/-42 could not do well and is NOT an extended 8048/8042) hardwired into most any PC chipset.
- One in most PC keyboards.
- An 8051 or 8048 in many household appliances that were button-and-LED controlled.
- One 8051 or 8048 in most VCRs and VFD-interfaced HiFi devices.
- One 8051 (or 80196! Another intel MCU, not an 8051), often the SAB80C515 or SAB80C517, in quite some early car ECUs.
- Probably a couple of them around even a modern car.
- One 8051 in a typical electronic central heating controller.
- Often, one 8051 in a telephone with a non-graphic LCD display.
- In an SD card or USB stick, often a supercharged 1-cycle 8051 core in the controller chip (likely hardwired for cost efficiency).

Generally, anything where a mechanical control solution (that isn't math heavy) is replaced by digital control, but without a graphic LCD (handling display fonts on an base, 12-cycle 8051 doesn't leave much capacity for anything else. Especially all the bit-wrangling to drive displays that want their data as 8-bit pieces of a row!), suspect an 8051 at work.

Often not 8051: film cameras (very custom stuff), toasters (4 bit cores), electronic door locks (PIC), calculators, simple digital watches (hardwired), printers (80188, ARM), optical mice (68HCxxx)...

Comment: Do you mean 12-cycle (vs 16-cycle) 8051?

Comment: Nice writeup, except that the 8048 (etc.) is *not* part of the MCS-51 family. While the MCS-51 was developed as a replacement for the MCS-48, it is not plug compatible - not even binary. Compatimbility exists only on source code level and only with restrictions. So it's more like 8088 and 8080. You may want to remove these references for a clear picture.

Comment: Oh, and similar the 80196. It's a member of the MCS-96 family (8061, 8096, ...), which is similar to the 8051, but an independant development as well. Again only partiality source code compatible.

Comment: Clarified. I think mentioning the MCS-48 and MCS-96 is important in that context, though, since these share some of the markets mentioned... And actually, the 8048 is as ugly as a PIC in architecture :)

Comment: Great. But wouldn't it be better t drop mentioning them all together - after all, the number of PC keyboard controllers are dwarfed by a magnitude or two by 8051 controlled dishwashers allone, aren't they? The sucess of these odd microcontrollers is the backbone of today's world - and the 8051 story works for itself, doesn't it?

Comment: Wouldn't underestimate keyboards - given that many of us, in the corporate world, do treat them as disposables these days, probably wearing out 3 to 5 of them over the lifetime of a desktop PC. Also, I suspect you have a lot of MCS-48 in the dishwasher and washing machine world too...

Comment: The original IBM-PC keyboard and in a lot of clones of it it was 8048 controller that was used, not the 8051. Some keyboard manufacturers used other controllers (Preh a well-known German keyboard manufacturer used 68705 for example).

Comment: Cherry often used 8051...